Analytics events show in Google Tag Manager preview but only some show in Analytics DebugView
I embedded Google Analytics via Google Tag Manager following Google's documentation.
I set it up so it triggers on initialisation - all pages.

When I preview GTM, the events all show fine – each pageview triggers a pageView hit.

However, the GA debugView it barely shows any events... It shows about 1 out of every 5 that I can see in the GTM preview.
It also seems random which events are picked up. Sometimes it's only the initial page view, sometimes it's only the second or third...

There are no console errors.
Any ideas what's going on and how to fix this please?

Just to be clear, you're not actually using G-XXXXXXXX as your GA4 tag ID?

Turns out I just had to restart my browser. Really annoying bug with the debugger.
